# Comparing array with 2 dimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to compare a certain character array with a two dimensional array but I'm not sure how I'd do this. Say I had the following code:

```
char colors[10][4] = {"bla", "bro", "red", "ora", "yel", "gre", "blu", "vio", "gra", "whi"};
char name[11] = "red";
```

I want to see if the value of name[] is the same as any of the "rows" in the two dimensional array colors. If so, it needs to return which row was equal. So in the code above, it would return a 2 since red is the 2nd value in the two dimensional array.

This is what I've been trying:

```
int x, y;
for(x=0; x<10; x++) {
        if (strncmp(colors, name) == 0) {
              break;
    }
}
```

And then theoretically, I can grab the value of x to find which row it was from. Obviously this will not work. :/ Any thoughts here?

Comment: You have to index ...

Comment: Why will it not work, have you tried it, what happened?

Comment: It won't compile since the type of `colors` isn't `char*`, it's `char**` (or `char[]*`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to index the array, (`colors[x]`) and not forget the last argument to `strncmp`, which is the length of the strings to compare. Change

```
strncmp(colors,  name)
```

to

```
strncmp(colors[x], name, strlen(name))
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you forgot the **[x]** :

```
int x;
for(x=0; x<10; x++) {
        if (strncmp(colors[x], name) == 0) {
              break;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, that was my problem. Also I didn't specify a length of the string. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see one possible error. You aren't indexing the location in colors that you are trying to compare.

```
int x, y;
for(x=0; x<10; x++) {
    if (strncmp(colors[x], name) == 0) {
          printf("Found the color %s", name);
          break;
    }
}
```